# How to perform an EAGER fetch in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I was wondering in JPQL (not on the entity mappings) how to explicitly fetch an associated field eagerly.

I have `ContactAddressLink` (took out the annotations for brevity)

```java
class ContactAddressLink {
  Contact contact;
  Address address;
  ... some extra fields ...
}
```

So I have a query that would go

```
select cal from Contact c, Address a, ContactAddressLink cal where
cal.contact = c and cal.address = a
```

Which gives me the query I expected.  However, since I would use the addresses after I see a bunch of queries getting the each address.

What I want to do is something like

```
select cal eager fetch cal.a from Contact c, Address a, ContactAddressLink cal where
cal.contact = c and cal.address = a
```

I recall seeing something like that, but I can't remember the exact syntax.

Comment: I am thinking it's a `FETCH JOIN` or something like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup. You are right. The syntax is `[inner|left] join fetch`. Example :

```
select cal from ContactAddressLink cal
inner join fetch cal.contact c
inner join fetch cal.address a
where cal.id = 123456789
```

If you want to match `ContactAddressLink` if it has `Contact`/`Address` , use `inner join fetch`.

If you want to  match `ContactAddressLink` even if it does not have `Contact`/`Address` , use `left join fetch`.

Comment: And assuming I don't want the contact (just the address) I take out the `fetch` before ca1.contact c?

Comment: Yup . If you want  your matching condition is totally not affected by the `Contact` , you can even take out `inner join fetch cal.contact c` . If you just want to not eager fetch `Contact` and still want  match `ContactAddressLink` that has `Contact` , you can just take out the word `fetch`.

Comment: Just tried it, unfortunately still gives a separate query for each of the related table when I do the trace.  I am thinking it may just be a limitation of the implementation rather than the spec which had indicated it should fetch already.

Comment: Interesting . You use Hibernate or EclipseLink ? set `@ManyToOne` 's fetchType in those to-one fields to LAZY yet ?

Comment: I use Hibernate via Spring Data JPA.  There's no "reverse mapping" so there's no @ManyToOne, but I use `@OneToOne`.  There's no FetchType defined in the Java entities,  Anyway per the spec it should work but it does not appear so.

Comment: The default fetchType is in the annotation is EAGER, but it is still doing it in separate queries.

Comment: Yup. How about set it to `@Lazy` to see if there are any difference ?

Answer (score 1):

Remember as per `JPA Specification` all `@OneToOne` and `@ManyToOne` are fetched eagerly. You should change it to lazy if not, you will fetch those objects always.

Comment: I want it to fetch eagerly.  However, I wanted JPA to fetch them in one SQL call.  Right now it makes several SQL calls.